# MAX(date) is not Giving correct ANSWER in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

max(date) is giving me a wrong answer as shown in the picture and code used is
select new_date from datemap;
select max(new_date) from datemap;

[image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a `date`, this result is what you'd get if it is a `varchar` (which of course would be silly...)

Comment: If you store your data as a string you can expect it to be sorted as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date is not a date!  Fix the data so it is stored as a date.

In the meantime, you can convert it on-the-fly:

```
select max(str_to_date(new_date, '%d-%m-%y'))
```

Comment: thanks, it's working @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff